# Authentication to REST API: digest type with cookie (c#)

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, cookies, fiddler

I have a service REST API where I tryied to connect.
Using browser all is ok.

But in c# I always have an unauthorized answer.

I investigated this issue using fiddler and find out that in first unsuccessful reuest server returns some cookie, and browser use it in next session together with username/password (digest type).In this case second session is successful.

But when I try to send request using c# (I tried work with System.Net.WebClient and HttpWebRequest) I don't get response (I had timeout exception after some time).

My code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
Uri prefix = new Uri(Url);
cache.Add(prefix, "Digest", new NetworkCredential(login, password));
webClient.Credentials = cache;
...

string response = webClient.DownloadString(restRequest);
```

Last line throws exception.

When I investigated this issue in Fiddler I found out that in first session with status 401 we recieved cookie (like on  picture below). 
[fiddler's picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-PbFrHlebX3cXJLeWdScnl6X3M/view?usp=sharing)
Browser sends this cookie in next request and authentication happens successfully.
But in c# I couldn't geet this response with status 401. As I see in fiddler studio try to open new session 10-20 times during each next seconds before timeout exception will be thrown. And my response in null.

Also I have other environment without required cookie, there my code is working.

Please, give me a piece of advise hoe to get response with Status 401 and get cookie from it to set it to another request.

thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using HttpWebRequest with defined empty (not null) CookieContainer.

My code:

```
HttpWebRequest request1;
HttpWebResponse response1 = null;
String responseBody;
request1 = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestString);
request1.Credentials = cache;

request1.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();            

response1 = (HttpWebResponse) request1.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        responseBody = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

In this implementation after first session with status 401 requests provide cookie from first session to next one and it returns with status code 200 OK.